# Class number of $\Bbb Q(a)$ with $a^3-a+1 = 0$ is $1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

> Show that class number of $\Bbb Q(a)$ with $a^3-a+1 = 0$ is $1$.

Any hints? Suggested theorems? I don't want a solution.

Mistaken Attempt:

Apply Kummer-Dedekind to $x^3-x+1 \pmod p$. For just p=2 , we get $x^2(x-1)(x+1)+1 \pmod 2$ so it doesn't factor. Similarly, for larger primes we get $x^2(x-1)(x+1)+1 \pmod p$. Thus, we only get principal ideals and so the ideal class group contains only the trivial i.e. class number is 1.

Comment: Clearly, an integer polynomial $f(x)$ in one variable cannot be irreducible modulo all primes: plug in any $\alpha$ for which $f(\alpha)\neq \pm 1$ and take any prime divisor $p$ of $f(\alpha)$. Then $f(\alpha)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, so $(x-\alpha)$ is a factor of $\bar{f}$ modulo $p$.

Comment: any alternative ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The [*Minkowski bound*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_bound) for $k=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-x+1)$ is $M_k=\frac{8}{9\pi}\sqrt{23}\approx 1.4$.